# Why a particular page from "React-router-dom" is having 'not-found text message' at its bottom in browser window (react-router-dom version -6)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**Description** - I made a `Route.tsx` file where I would be storing all of my routes, into the app, including the `App.tsx` (at path:  '/') itself.

Here's my `Route.tsx` file - also (Approach 1)

```
import { lazy } from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, Navigate, RouteObject } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../layout/App";
 
// react - lazy paint
const Home = lazy(() => import("../pages/home/Home"));
const Toys = lazy(() => import("../pages/products/Toys"));
const Books = lazy(() => import("../pages/learning/Learning"));
const NotFound = lazy(() => import("../pages/notFound/NotFound"));
 
export const routes : RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App />, 
    children: [
      { path: "toys", element: <Toys /> },
      { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
      { path: "books", element: <Books /> },
      { path: "not-found", element: <NotFound /> },
      { path: "*", element: <Navigate replace to = {"/not-found"} /> }
    ]
  }
];
 
// export all routes
export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
```

These all above mentioned routes are meant to wrapped inside of a container (from Material UI). Whilst, there is one page, which I wish not to enclose into the container, named `Cars.tsx`, so I modified my `App.tsx` file like the one mentioned below:

App.tsx file

```
import { Container, CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { Fragment, lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Outlet, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import AppLoad from "./AppLoad";
import Header from "./Header";
 
// react - lazy imports
const Cars = lazy(() => import("../pages/cars"));
 
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Header />
 
        // for lazy paint load ...
        <Suspense fallback={<AppLoad message={'Please wait. Loading ...'} />}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="cars" element={<Cars />} />
            // this particular page, I don't want to enclose it into 
            // the container, because it contains a hero image.
          </Routes>
 
          <Container maxWidth={'xl'}>
            <Outlet /> // all the rest of pages are inside of container
          </Container>
        </Suspense>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Problem Description** - Everything is working fine, only problem I am facing is when I am at `"/cars"` page, at the very bottom of the page, it is also rendering `"Not-Found"` (previously it was solved by `<Switch />` in `react-router-dom`'s version < 6).

**Expected Behavior** - I don't want to see `"Not Found"` message at the very bottom of "Cars" page. How to fix it?

I know, the fix would be very simple, but I couldn't figure it out.

Also, I would like to ask whether or not the above mentioned approach is better (like creating a separate file for `Route`, and then using it as `<Outlet />`), or the traditional approach is better where we have as.

**Approach 2**

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='page1' element={<Page1 />} />
  <Route path='page2' element={<Page2 />} />
  <Route path='page1' element={<Page3 />} />
</Routes>
```

Would it be going to make any difference into the First content-ful paint loading of any routed page so far if I work with any of the approach as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it seems is that the `App` component is rendering *both* an `Outlet` for nested routes ***and*** a `Routes` component for the `"/cars"` descendent route. When the path is `"/cars"` the `App` component is rendered and renders the matching `"/cars"` descendent route is rendered, but there is no matching nested `"/cars"` route so it looks like the `NotFound` route/component is additionally rendered in the `Outlet`.

If the goal is to ***not*** render the `"/cars"` route and `Cars` component inside the `Container` then I'd recommend creating an additional layout route and conditionally render the nested routes into the appropriate layout routes.

Example:

```
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ContainerLayout = () => (
  <Container maxWidth="xl">
    <Outlet />
  </Container>
);
```

routes.tsx

```
import { lazy } from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, Navigate, RouteObject } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../layout/App";
 
// react - lazy paint
const Home = lazy(() => import("../pages/home/Home"));
const Toys = lazy(() => import("../pages/products/Toys"));
const Books = lazy(() => import("../pages/learning/Learning"));
const NotFound = lazy(() => import("../pages/notFound/NotFound"));
const Cars = lazy(() => import("../pages/cars"));
 
export const routes : RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App />, 
    children: [
      {
        element: <ContainerLayout />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Home /> },
          { path: "toys", element: <Toys /> },
          { path: "books", element: <Books /> },
          { path: "not-found", element: <NotFound /> }
        ],
      },
      { path: "cars" element: <Cars /> },
      { path: "*", element: <Navigate replace to="/not-found" /> }
    ]
  },
];
 
// export all routes
export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
```

App.tsx

```
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import AppLoad from "./AppLoad";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
 
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Header />
 
    // for lazy paint load ...
    <Suspense fallback={<AppLoad message="Please wait. Loading ..." />}>
      <Outlet />
    </Suspense>
   </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Drew Reese , for helping and solving out the query.  Highly appreciative